# Typo3 Extension "Calendarize" - ICS Import with custom fields

Tags: plugins, typo3, icalendar, typo3-extensions

I'd like to modify the ICS import of the EXT "calendarize" (https://github.com/lochmueller/calendarize) to have some additional custom values (like OpenEndTime or maybe image-url)
OR
any possibility to add a custom event from a MySQL/PHP source.

Can anyone give me some hints on which parts I have to edit since I'm not experienced with TYPO3 extensions (maybe even with tips for best practice since I guess that upgrading might overwrite the changes I made).

Thank you very much in advance!!!

I can see that most stuff might have to be changed here "calendarize/Classes/Ical/" and I tried to get openEndTime working since there's already an entry which seems to be prepared, but it failed and I don't know why (no error shown in TYPO3 log, nor in PHP logs).

The ICS-file for import looks like this...

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:PHP
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Events
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
TZNAME:CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
TZNAME:CET
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20230512T200000
allDay : false
openEndTime : true
DTSTAMP:20230509T101336Z
LOCATION:Bürgersaal
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:Programm Titel
UID:19ca14e7ea6328a42e0eb13d585e4c22
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20230513T200000
allDay : false
openEndTime : true
DTSTAMP:20230509T101336Z
LOCATION:Location
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:Programm Titel
UID:a5771bce93e200c36f7cd9dfd0e5deaa
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

calendarize/Classes/Ical/DissectEventAdapter.php

- changed "return false" to "return true" in line 174

```
    public function isOpenEndTime(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `cweagans/composer-patches` package to create a patch file so that you don't modify the TER extension. In this way, extension updates will not be a problem.

```
diff -ruN orig-file  modified-file  > file.patch
```

and then you need to include the same in your composer file as well.

```
"extra": {
        "helhum/typo3-console": {
            "install-extension-dummy": false
        },
        "patches": {
            "georgringer/news": {
               "This is just an example patch": "path to your patch file.patch"
            }
        }
    }
```

All this applies only to a composer-based instance.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that aspect! Unfortunately it's not composer-based. But I'll keep that in mind.
I'm sorry, I can't upvote your answer yet :(